# Convert learned parameters to pb file

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I have a numpy file which looks like this,

```
array({'bbox_reg_1': {'weights': array([[[[ 1.41573034e-03, -1.68433134e-03, -1.46378449e-03],
         [ 4.94853244e-04,  2.70358869e-04,  1.17152464e-03],
         [ 1.46097073e-03,  1.64969335e-03,  2.44257652e-04],
         [-1.96780078e-03, -1.16519595e-03,  1.38781685e-03],   
         [ 9.05778143e-05,  1.55463757e-03, -1.17503619e-03],
         [ 6.90302986e-04,  1.20219309e-03, -6.66214619e-04],
         ...............
         ...............
         ...............  
         'biases': array([0.15425067, 0.22107883, 0.15874247,0.18794474, 0.3142768 ,
         0.22744565, 0.4702694 , 0.37981156, 0.2936976 , 0.26642567,
         0.27769807, 0.19335541, 0.56588143, 0.19396164, 0.22467329], dtype=float32)}}, dtype=object)
```

The context is i am trying to convert a caffe model to tensorflow.Which takes in the caffe model and returs this file.What i am confused about is how can i convert this to a pb file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to see a comment as to why you downvote

Comment: It would be not bad to know how you get those values from Caffe model. Anyway, there is software like https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow/ which does the job. This blogpost shows how to use it: https://ndres.me/post/convert-caffe-to-tensorflow/ . By inspecting the source code you might find what you need.

Comment: cool ,Thanks for the help